# What are the use of rand_mode(val)?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

according to uvm_users_guide_1.1, page 152, these 2 implementations are shown:
First:

```
class my_seq extends uvm_sequence #(my_item);
... // Constructor and UVM automation macros go here.
    // See Section 4.8.2
virtual task body();
 `uvm_create(req)
 req.addr.rand_mode(0); // Disables randomization of addr
 req.dc1.constraint_mode(0); // Disables constraint dc1
 req.addr = 27;
 ...
endtask : body
endclass: my_seq
```

and:

```
class my_seq2 extends uvm_sequence #(my_item);
... // Constructor and UVM automation macros go here.
    // See Section 4.8.2
virtual task body();
`uvm_create(req)
req.addr = 27;
req.data = 4;
// No randomization. Use a purely pre-generated item.
`uvm_send(req)
endtask : body
endclass: my_seq2
```

What will be the difference if I`ll not use the "rand_mode(0)" and "constraint_mode(0)" as in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

`rand_mode(0)` is feature of SystemVerilog that the UVM example is using to freeze a random variable like it was a non-rand variable when calling `randomize()`. You usually do this when you need to fix one random variable to a particular value, but want others to be randomized as usual.

The second example shows how you can set all the random variables without ever calling `randomize()`. Many people forget (especially if they are coming from another language *e*) that when doing constrained random verification that you don't always have to call `randomize()`. They'll go out of their way to add constraints like

req.randomize() with { addr == 27; data == 4; }
when it would have been easier to just to do it as the second example shows.

See sections 18.8 and 18.7 of the IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM.

Comment: Why they choose not  to write rand_mode(0) and constraint_mode(0) methods in the second example as in the first one?

Comment: Because they never call `randomze()` and those methods have no effect in the second example. This fact is hidden by the UVM sequence macros when using uvm_send(). I strongly recommend not using those macros and using the sequence API directly. See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/help-uvmdo-macro-uvm-methodology#reply-38592

Answer (score 0):

The user guide gives you a hint:

```
NOTE — You might need to disable a constraint to avoid a conflict.
```

In `my_seq`, there could be a difference if you call `randomize()`.  Consider this scenario:

```
rand bit [5:0] addr;
rand bit [7:0] data;
constraint dc1 { data==addr; data != 27; }
```

`randomize` will fail if you disable randomization of `addr`, set `addr`=27 and don't disable the `dc1` constraint.